# Codeigniter RESTful API - How to get data with post method

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I'm using the Codeigniter RESTful API to send data to my Backbone App. For example like this:

```
public function a_get()  
{ 
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM `artists` WHERE formated_name LIKE 'A%' LIMIT 0, 50";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

    if($data) {
        $this->response($data, 200);
    } else {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter a!'), 404);
    }
}
```

Anyhow, I have to remove the `LIMIT`-statement so display All the data, in this case Artists with the beginning letter "A" and that is huge load of data. For that I cant use the GET method because it truncates the string over the `LIMIT`-statement, so I have to use the POST method, but I dont know how to achieve this. Anyone knows how to solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you aren't using CodeIgniter's Active Record implementation? That would potentially make it easier.

Comment: Also, this looks like you're querying the database from the controller, which you should not be doing - any database queries should be done from the model.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Since I use Backbone Codeigniter's Models and Views are of no use...

Comment: Views are of no use in this context, but the models most certainly aren't.

Comment: Well, not sure of that...

Comment: If your database queries are kept in the model, then you can make the same query from several different places with ease, which is the whole point of using an MVC framework. Making a database query from a controller is a terrible practice.

Comment: That might be true but remember that I'm using BackboneJS, different situation...

Comment: The fact that you're using Backbone is entirely irrelevant. It just removes the need for a view. It remains good practice to place your database queries in the model, so that they can be reused if necessary. They do not belong in the controller.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it make sense to accept the letter as a parameter and pass it through to the query rather than creating a hard-coded route for a specific letter?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [philsturgeon's library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), then:

```
$this->get('blah'); // GET param
$this->post('blah'); // POST param
$this->put('blah'); // PUT param
```

This is on readme.md.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you tried this, but lets say you have your POST sent with $_POST['letter']. Also remember to filter the data. You might find use in Models to do operations like queries or data modification, but I think that you will get to it eventually.

```
public function a_post()  
{ 
    $letter = ucfirst(substr(mysql_real_escape_string($this->post('letter')), 0, 1));
    $this->load->database();
    if(isset($letter) && !empty($letter))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM `artists` WHERE formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%' LIMIT 0, 50";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();

        if($data) {
            $this->response($data, 200);
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter '.$letter.'!'), 404);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists because of the empty string!'), 404);
    }
}
```